# Update function code igniter does not save changes

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

hi am making this edit function in my code igniter hmvc project. i am getting the value of the things i want to edit, and it is posted to the textbox i want to. but, i cannot save the changes. my model is this,

```
public function update(){

    $sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET PROVINCE = ? WHERE PROV_ID = ?";
    $input = array(
            'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE'),
            'PROV_ID' =>$this->uri->segment(3)
            );

  //  print_r($input);
   // exit;
    $query =  $this->db->query($sql, $input);
    return $query;

}
```

when i print_r the input, it says

```
Array ( [PROVINCE] => Province [PROV_ID] => )
```

i think dont get the uri value. how can i fix this?

here is my controller

```
/// EDIT

    public function update(){

        $data['content'] = $this->Provinces_Model->getrow();
        $data['content_view'] = 'Provinces/edit_view';
        $this->templates->admin_template($data);

    }

    public function update_row(){


         if($this->Provinces_Model->update()){
            redirect('Provinces/index');
         }else{
            $this->update();
         }

    }

}
```

here is my full model

//// EDIT

```
public function getrow(){

    $this->db->where('PROV_ID', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $query->row();

}
public function update(){

    $sql = "UPDATE $this->table SET PROVINCE = ? WHERE PROV_ID = ?";
    $input = array(
            'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE'),
            'PROV_ID' =>$this->uri->segment(3)
            );

  //  print_r($input);
   // exit;
    $query =  $this->db->query($sql, $input);
    return $query;

}
```

here is my edit view

```
            <?php

                echo form_open('Provinces/update_row');
            ?>

            <p>
                <label class="field" for="PROVINCE"><span>*</span>Province Name:</label>
                <input type = "text" name="PROVINCE" class ="textbox-300" value= "<?php echo $content->PROVINCE; ?>">
                <label class = "error"><?php echo form_error("PROVINCE"); ?></label>
            </p>

            <?php
                echo form_submit('submit','Update');
                echo form_close();
            ?>
```

here is the part of my table where i click to edit

```
<td><?php echo anchor("Provinces/update/$i->PROV_ID","<i class='fa  fa-edit'>" ); ?></td>
```

Comment: 'PROV_ID' =>$this->uri->segment(3)    <- check this value. may be it's null

Comment: try "$this->db->where('PROV_ID', $this->uri->segment(2));" and check..

Comment: i got null always on uri segment but i have the value on my uri.

Comment: that's your problem. fix it .i'm verty shure because i had same problem haha

Comment: no i get the problem. i just dont know how to fix it. i have the uri segment. but when i pass it to update_row() the uri also changes

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function update() {

    $input = array(
        'PROVINCE' => $this->input->post('PROVINCE'),
        'PROV_ID' =>$this->uri->segment(3) 
    );

    $this->db->where('prov_id',$input['PROV_ID']);
    $this->db->update('province',$input);
}
```

Comment: says UPDATE province SET PROVINCE = 'province a', PROV_ID = NULL WHERE prov_id IS NULL –

Comment: $this->db->where('prov_id',$input['PROV_ID']); <- edit this line

however this code is guideline

Answer (score 0):

get the all segments of URI in an array
For that use this line...

```
$segs = $this->uri->segment_array();

foreach ($segs as $segment)
{
    echo $segment;
    echo '<br />';
}
```

and use that specific key to get the ID or something else!!